# How to repartition in spark based on column?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to repartition the dataframe based on day column.
Like, I have 90 days data in dataframe and I want to partition data based on day, so that I have each day in each partition

I want a syntax like below..
df.repartition("day",90)

Where
day => column in dataframe
90 => number of partitions I want

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by

```
import spark.implicits._
df.repartition(df.select($"day").count().toInt, $"day")
```